# Cumulative update fails to update files though version number of file is updated

Tags: wix, installshield, patch, wix3.5, msp

We released an application version 2.10.3.X recently.

And got some request for fix and we released a small update (the version is 2.10.4.X). [ one dll with version 2.10.4.1 and 2 xap files are changed]

Now they need one more small update (2.10.5.x) [one more dll with version 2.10.5.1 and xap is changed].

The update should be cumulative. (2.10.5.x should install  2.10.4.x changes also if it is directly installed on top of 2.10.3.X ):

- When installing 2.10.5.x on top of 2.10.3.X it is installing the changes correctly.[All the 2 dll and 3 xaps are replaced]
- When installing 2.10.4.x on top of 2.10.4.X ,it is not updating the files. I checked the msp log file.

It says same version and won't update. ( but the dll version is changed correctly).

The msi was written in wix and the patch is being done via InstallShield 2010 service pack1. Instead of using 2 previous msi , I am enabling "Minor Update to Target RTM version (MST 3.1 required)

Answer (score 1):

For it to be a minor upgrade, the version much change. And for Windows Installer to consider it a version change, one of the first three numbers must change. Thus 2.10.4.x to 2.10.4.y is a small update instead of a minor upgrade, and becomes much harder to reason about. Change one of the first three numbers, such as your other working example scenarios describe, and it sounds like you have it working.

Comment: Actually MSI does not count the forth element of version as a change. So you have to change the first three numbers *A.B.C*.x.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Correct. That's what I believe my answer said.